# Why does "FOO=bar echo $FOO" NOT work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, environment-variables

For many years, I use `DESTDIR=/somewhere make install` to set a temp path before a installation operation for testing purpose, so I naively think it works for any command line.

But it does NOT work with `FOO=bar echo $FOO`, to my surprise!

It looks like that `FOO=bar bash -c 'echo $FOO'` works well.

Would anyone please tell me the reason behind this?
If every time I must use the after form, it is bother a little.